# Django model with methods to register various kinds of events

Tags: python, object-oriented

Is there any better way to define the function in the class which shares most of the same parameters like `functools.partial`?

```
from django.db import models


class RegisterUserAction(models.Manager):
    def register_adhoc_created(self, **kwargs):
        return self.create(action_type="ADHOC_CREATED", **kwargs)

    def register_adhoc_deleted(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(action_type="ADHOC_DELETED", **kwargs)

    def register_broadcast_created(self, **kwargs):
        return self.create(action_type="BROADCAST_CREATED", **kwargs)
```

Comment: How you call this method? You tried override the create method of models.Manager and verify the type received ? As a if type == 'some_type' to do this..

Comment: My intention is to call function which pass defined type along with the kwargs. there is create method also. I use this in Django models class like `objects = RegisterUserAction()`. then call `<ModelClass>.objects.register_broadcast_created(**kwargs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be keep a map of these method names and related `action_type`. Now we can override [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) to check if one of these methods were accessed and return the partial function with related `action_type`.

```
from functools import partial

from django.db import models


register_map = {
    'register_adhoc_created': 'ADHOC_CREATED',
    'register_adhoc_deleted': 'ADHOC_DELETED',
    'register_broadcast_created': 'BROADCAST_CREATED',
}


class RegisterUserAction(models.Manager):

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr in register_map:
            return partial(self.create, action_type=register_map[attr])
        return super(RegisterUserAction, self).__getattribute__(attr)
```

Personally I would do something like this only when the number of such methods are huge and are polluting the code base. Because simplicity in this case greater than being DRY and other devs will have to spend some understanding it. Also because of this custom implementation the code editors won't allow developers to jump into respective code because such method(s) actually doesn't exist.

Comment: I initially tried this approach but thought this might not be the readable one. Seeing similar answer might help me to change my view toward this approach. Thank you for your answer.